# How to make csv-align-mode default in tsv-mode?

Tags: init-file, hooks, directory-local-variables

I'm editing tab separated file with Emacs and [csv-mode.el](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/csv-mode.html). When the document is open, I can align the columns with `M-x csv-align-mode`. How to make it automatically aligned when I open the file?

Both `~/.emacs` and `.dir-locals.el` based solutions are fine.

I'm pretty new with Emacs so this might be generic elisp question but I'm not sure.

PS. [An example of .tsv file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zouppen/pumpunjuksautin/modbus/avr/commands.tsv)

Answer (score 1):

Add `(add-hook 'csv-mode-hook 'csv-align-mode)` to `~/.emacs` and it works. Note: It's *csv*, not *tsv*, even though editing .tsv files.

My skills don't yet suffice to make it in `.dir-locals.el`.

Comment: "Note: It's csv, not tsv, even though editing .tsv files." - tsv-mode is derived from csv-mode, which means it will run the hooks in both `csv-mode-hook` as well as `tsv-mode-hook`.  This means you could also just add it to `tsv-mode-hook` if you didn't want this to apply to csv files.